# Application not working after upgrading app to springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

App was running fine till 2.0.0.RELEASE. When I upgraded it to 2.0.4.RELEASE. 
Server Comes up but giving this error continously.

apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause","stack_trace":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/core/instrument/util/TimeDecayingMax

Swagger not opening up.

Comment: Have you checked what io.micrometer version is downloaded in your project? Looks like spring boot dependency manager is not aligned with the one you have in your local repo.

Comment: Please add the POM file to the question.

Comment: Thanks @dcalap . Was able to resolve issue after you suggestion. It was the mircrometer version as well the maven dependency manager issue.